# Find repeat values in numpy nd array

Tags: python, numpy

My data samples are each a numpy array of shape e.g. (100, 100, 9), and I have 10 of these concatenated into a single array `foo` of shape (10, 100, 100, 9). Over the 10 data samples, I'd like to find the indices of repeat values. So for example, if `foo[0, 42, 42, 3] = 0.72` and `foo[0, 42, 42, 7] = 0.72`, I'd like an output that reflects this. What is an efficient way of doing so?

I'm thinking a boolean output array of shape (100, 100, 9), but is there a better approach than looping to compare each data sample (quadratic runtime for the number of data samples (10))?

Comment: Do you just want to flag any value that has a duplicate or do you want a dictionary with data-values as the keys, and duplicates indices as the dictionary values?

Comment: @James the question was left generic not specifying the precise data returned so as not to constrain the possible solutions, but I'm thinking a boolean array that simply flags the duplicates by index (as suggested above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below snippet, `dups` is the desired result: a boolean array that shows which indices are duplicates. There's also a `delta` threshold, so any difference in values <= this threshold is a duplicate.

```
delta = 0.
dups = np.zeros(foo.shape[1:], dtype=bool)
for i in xrange(foo.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(foo.shape[0]):
        if i==j: continue
        dups += abs(foo[i] - foo[j]) <= delta
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using `argsort` on each sample. Not pretty, not fast but does the job.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def dupl(a, axis=0, make_dict=True):
    a = np.moveaxis(a, axis, -1)
    i = np.argsort(a, axis=-1, kind='mergesort')
    ai = a[tuple(np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, a.shape))][:-1]) + (i,)]
    same = np.zeros(a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1]+1,), bool)
    same[..., 1:-1] = np.diff(ai, axis=-1) == 0
    uniqs = np.where((same[..., 1:] & ~same[..., :-1]).ravel())[0]
    same = (same[...,1:]|same[...,:-1]).ravel()
    reps = np.split(i.ravel()[same], np.cumsum(same)[uniqs[1:]-1])
    grps = np.searchsorted(uniqs, np.arange(0, same.size, a.shape[-1]))
    keys = ai.ravel()[uniqs]
    if make_dict:
        result = np.empty(a.shape[:-1], object)
        result.ravel()[:] = [dict(zip(*p)) for p in np.split(
                np.array([keys, reps], object), grps[1:], axis=-1)]
        return result
    else:
        return keys, reps, grps

a = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,100,100,9))
axis = 0
result = dupl(a, axis)

print('shape, axis, time (sec) for 10 trials:', 
      a.shape, axis, timeit(lambda: dupl(a, axis=axis), number=10))
print('same without creating dict:', 
      a.shape, axis, timeit(lambda: dupl(a, axis=axis, make_dict=False),
                            number=10))

#check
print("checking result")
am = np.moveaxis(a, axis, -1)
for af, df in zip(am.reshape(-1, am.shape[-1]), result.ravel()):
    assert len(set(af)) + sum(map(len, df.values())) == len(df) + am.shape[-1]
    for k, v in df.items():
        assert np.all(np.where(af == k)[0] == v)
print("no errors")
```

prints:

```
shape, axis, time (sec) for 10 trials: (10, 100, 100, 9) 0 5.328339613042772
same without creating dict: (10, 100, 100, 9) 0 2.568383438978344
checking result
no errors
```

Comment: There are smells all over this code, and there's so much miscellaneous sorting it's like this is trying to be inefficient.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain bit harsh don't you think? Besides unlike yours this has reasonable complexity not O(n k^2) but O(n (log n / k + k log k)). It's not easy on the eye I admit that but don't thrash it just because it's beyond you.